# Java web application working with Scrutmydocs

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Does anyone know of a good example with a Java web application that uses `Scrutmydocs`, or any other `ElasticSearch` Client.  I have a sample web app running: `www.TenantTalk.com` that I need to add a search box to.  The search will call `Scrutmydocs` or `Elasticsearch`. The Database will be much larger.

Right now it is a java jsp app using MySQL using JDBC and SQL on Tomcat. When a new record or change is made to the database it must make it into Scrutmydocs or Elasaticsearch.

You help will be greatly appreciated.

The login for `www.TenantTalk.com` is demo/demo

I have searched everywhere but cannot find an example that spells out where you call `Scrutmydocs` from a Java application when the user adds, edits, or deletes a record from the database and perform searches on that date.

Answer (score 0):

scrutmydocs is not an elasticsearch client. It is a full web application.
It basically uses elasticsearch native client. So you can have a look at its source code.

That said, you probably want to look directly at [elasticsearch java API documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

Also, this hands-on source code could help you. See [answers branch](https://github.com/elasticsearchfr/hands-on/tree/answers).